# Test Coverage not show in Sonar entegration in .netcore 3.2

Tags: c#, docker, sonarqube, .net-core-3.0

I want to integrate Sonar integration into my `.netcore 3.2` project.

I did it but test coverage was not shown in Sonar.

My docker sonar integration looks like this:

```
# install nodejs
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_11.x | bash - && apt-get install -y nodejs autoconf libtool nasm

ENV SolutionName  MyProject
# reviewing this choice
ENV SONAR_SCANNER_MSBUILD_VERSION 4.8.0.12008

ARG branchName
RUN wget https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanner-msbuild/releases/download/$SONAR_SCANNER_MSBUILD_VERSION/sonar-scanner-msbuild-$SONAR_SCANNER_MSBUILD_VERSION-netcoreapp3.0.zip
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -yy unzip 
RUN unzip sonar-scanner-msbuild-$SONAR_SCANNER_MSBUILD_VERSION-netcoreapp3.0.zip -d /sonar-scanner
# Install Sonar Scanner

RUN rm sonar-scanner-msbuild-$SONAR_SCANNER_MSBUILD_VERSION-netcoreapp3.0.zip
RUN chmod +x -R /sonar-scanner

# Sonar scanner start
RUN dotnet /sonar-scanner/SonarScanner.MSBuild.dll begin /d:sonar.host.url=http://sonar.mycompany.com /d:sonar.login=111111/k:$SolutionName:"$branchName" /n:$SolutionName:"$branchName" /v:1 /d:sonar.cs.opencover.reportsPaths="/app/tests/MyProject.Tests/coverage.opencover.xml"
RUN dotnet test ./tests/CustomerServices.Tests/MyProject.Tests.csproj /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutputFormat=opencover 
RUN dotnet publish ./src/MyProject.Api/MyProject.Api.csproj -o /publish
RUN dotnet /sonar-scanner/SonarScanner.MSBuild.dll end /d:sonar.login=111111
# Sonar scanner end
```

This integration shows bugs, code smells and quality gates but does not show coverage.

I also install coverlet.msbuild on my test project for test coverage but there is still no test coverage on my Sonar screen.

My Jenkins build like this.

```
Test Run Successful.
Total tests: 684
     Passed: 684
 Total time: 9.9564 Seconds

Calculating coverage result...
  Generating report '/workdir/tests/MyProject.Tests/coverage.opencover.xml'

+--------+------+--------+--------+
| Module | Line | Branch | Method |
+--------+------+--------+--------+

+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|         | Line      | Branch    | Method    |
+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| Total   | 100%      | 100%      | 100%      |
+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| Average | Infinity% | Infinity% | Infinity% |
+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

How can I integrate Sonar for test coverage?

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass the dotnet test command before sonar scanner begin command because with dotnet test command we are generating the report with coverage.opencover.xml uisng the /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutputFormat=opencover

Please feel free to update the reuslt.
Thank you